Inserting footnotes in react-slate fails
I have been struggling with creating footnotes in react-slate. Inserting the first footnote works but at render of the second there is always an errormessage "Exception has occurred: Error: Cannot resolve a DOM node from Slate node: {"text":" "}"
I have tried many strategies to work around this, a persistant pattern is that it is always at render of the last node the exception occurs. I have for example tried to insert a special end-of-document marker both as custom element and as text element. Still the exception occurs after insertion of a footnote but at the last element in the document, the end-of-document marer or the second footnote. Standard text works as expected. My application builds on the rich text example from Slate, https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/richtext.tsx. the snippet here is inside the onKeyDown event handler as the application shold trig inertion of footnotes on '#'
if (text && (text.startsWith('#'))) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Remove the text that's been identified as a tag
    Transforms.delete(editor, { at: beforeRange });

    // Insert a new tag element marked as inline
    const alt = ['alt1', 'alt2', 'alt3'];
    const tagUuid = uuid();
    const tagElement = {
        type: 'tag',
        subtype: 'hashtag'
        children: [{ text: text }], // Keep the '#' in the display text
        id: tagUuid,
        annotation: '',
        alternatives: alt,
        footnoteNumber: alt && alt.length > 0 ? footnoteCounter : null
    };

    Transforms.insertNodes(editor, tagElement);

    // Step 2: Insert a new paragraph
    const pathToTagElement = findPathToTagElementByUUID(editor, tagUuid);
    const fakeParagraphPath = Path.next(pathToTagElement); 
    Transforms.insertNodes(editor, {
        type: 'paragraph',
        children: [{ text: ' ' }]
    }, { at: fakeParagraphPath });

    // Step 3: Move the selection to the new paragraph
    Transforms.select(editor, fakeParagraphPath);

    // Step 4: Insert the underscore or space
    Transforms.insertText(editor, ' '); // Or space for production

    Transforms.move(editor, { distance: 1, unit: 'offset' });

    if (event.key === ' ') {
        Transforms.insertText(editor, ' '); 
    }
    ReactEditor.focus(editor)
    
    if (tagElement.alternatives && tagElement.alternatives.length > 0) {
        Transforms.insertNodes(editor, {
            type: 'footnote',
            alternatives: tagElement.alternatives.flat(),
            children: [{ text: '' }],
            footnoteNumber: 'footnoteCounter',
            parentId: tagElement.id
        }, { at: Editor.end(editor, []) });
    }

}

